# Logs are printed twice using faust

Tags: python-3.x, logging, faust

Using python `Faust`, all of my logs are doubled.

As loggers are hierarchal, i want to prevent the downstream logger `father.son` from logging anything and propagate all the logs to upstream `father` logger.

I tried:

1 - setting `disable_existing_loggers` to `True` in the `dictConfig` when main is called

2 - adding filter (inside a handler) to a specific logger name using the `dictConfig`:

```
class LogPreventingFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return False

logging_config = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'filters': {
        'log_preventing_filter': {
            '()': LogPreventingFilter
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['log_preventing_filter']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'father.son': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console']
        }
    }
}

dictConfig(logging_config)
```

3 - adding the same logging_config to faust's app configurations `logging_config` (with and without `'disable_existing_loggers': True`) - in that case i could see logs from the logger i mentioned (`father.son`) but not from the `father`, even after i added the `father` logger to to faust config), nor logs from any other non-hierarichial logger ( like `getLogger("some_name_not_related_to_father")`).

ill mention that i tried to remove the filter and handler and it didnt make any change.

Worth to mention that the logs start to double only after i call faust's `app.main()`.

also worth mentioning that the loggers that i want to actually log data are all from imported modules, not part of the code that is visible for faust. only `father.son` logger is.

my code:

`some.imported.module`

```
father_logger = logging.getLogger("father")
some_other_logger = logging.getLogger("not_hierarchiali_related")

class MyGenericClass:
   // add filters and handlers and do some generic stuff
```

`stream_processing_module`

```
son_logger = logging.getLogger("father.son")

async def processing_function():
   // do some stuff
   son_logger.info("log this and that")
```

the module using faust:

```
son_logger = logging.getLogger("father.son")

@app.agent
async def stream_processing():
   // call the processing_function() for the other module for each record
   son_logger.info("log some data")

if __name__ == "main":
   son_logger.info("start")
   with MyGenericClass:
      app.main()
```

notice that only `son_logger` is visible to faust.
still - i want the father logger to do the printing and not the son logger.

any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to have the FULL code so we could try on our own machines. I could give ideas all day but that wouldn't be too much help if I can't verify it works on my own machine.

Comment: understood. i cant provide the whole code, but can do my best to answer anything that comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in the `Faust` [logging manuals](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/logging.html) that the application writes to an independent `root_logger` (you cant get it when calling `logging.getLogger()` on your python app) and must be set with at least one handler in the application configuration (`logging_config`) BEFORE starting the faust app (`app.main()`).
If you dont set the root logger up, Faust will do that for you, and might print both the log in the python app context AND the same log in the Faust app context.